# In some cases, rvest keeps connection open?

Tags: r, rvest

rvest seems to be putting TCP FDs in CLOSE_WAIT state in some cases.

Replication example:
On R terminal do:

```
library(rvest)
k<-html("http://materialresourcing.com/tags/diy")
```

This will return.

Now do NOT close the R prompt.

Now open normal command Terminal and do:

```
lsof | grep materialresourcing
```

And you will find that it has a TCP handle in CLOSE_WAIT state, forever. (i.e till the R session is closed)

And the rvest API doesn't seem to give control to force close connection.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

UPDATE:

In fact just doing:

```
library(curl)
k<-curl_download("http://materialresourcing.com/tags/diy", "a.txt")
```

also causes it

UPDATE IN RESPONSE TO @jeroen questions

---

```
> library(curl)
> h <- new_handle()
> l2<-"http://rediff.com"
> curl_download(l2,"b.txt",handle=h)
> system("lsof | grep rediff")
> l3<-"http://materialresourcing.com/tags/diy"
> curl_download(l3,"c.txt",handle=h)
> system("lsof | grep materialresourcing")
R         17936          xxxx    7u     IPv4            3559514      0t0     TCP ip-10-0-xx:40844->vps.materialresourcing.com:http (CLOSE_WAIT)
sh        18257          xxxx    7u     IPv4            3559514      0t0     TCP ip-10-0-xx:40844->vps.materialresourcing.com:http (CLOSE_WAIT)
grep      18259          xxxx    7u     IPv4            3559514      0t0     TCP ip-10-0-xx:40844->vps.materialresourcing.com:http (CLOSE_WAIT)
>
```

As you can see only for this link. CLOSE_WAIT shows. And same thing happens using rvest too. and gc() has no effect there.

Comment: If the unclosed connections are an issue, you can try `con <- curl::curl("https://httpbin.org/") ; pg <- readLines(con) ; close(con)` and then using `pg` with `read_html()` / `html()` like: `xml2::read_html(paste0(pg, collapse=""))`

Comment: @hrbrmstr if we are using `rvest` and `read_html`. Do we need `curl::curl` to open and close connections?

Comment: `rvest` shld handle connection management for you @PierreLafortune

Answer (score 2):

The connection is kept alive deliberately by the curl handle, so that it can be reused. The garbage collector automatically closes the connection when the handle object is deleted or goes out of scope. A simple demonstration:

```
# Connection is stored on a handle object
library(curl)
h <- new_handle()

# Connection is kept alive
curl_download("http://materialresourcing.com/tags/diy", "a.txt", handle = h)
system("lsof | grep materialresourcing")

# Still there :)
gc()
system("lsof | grep materialresourcing")

# Still there :)
rm(h)
system("lsof | grep materialresourcing")

# after handle gone, garbage collector closes connection
gc()
system("lsof | grep materialresourcing")
```

The garbage collector runs automatically every now and then in R, so curl cleans up after itself. However some packages that build on the `curl` package deliberately keep the handle around to provide persistence or better performance. So in that case the connection stays open until the application deletes the internal handle from the pool.

Comment: That is the case with most URLS. However with certain URLS (like this one above), it remains in CLOSE_WAIT (literally) forever. So could be an issue with at the server? Which curl isnt handling?

Comment: No it doesn't, I just tested it. I think you are confusing something. Is the connection still there in the last block if you run the example above?

Comment: I have updated the question with latest tests. As you can see only for this link, the handle is held. Doesnt happen with all. Pls let me know if I am missing something. Same things happens with rvest

Comment: This is because `rediff.com` does not support http keep-alive. Keep alive doesn't hold things up, it makes things faster. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: here is the potential issue. When rvest is used on certain links (like this one), the fDs are not released and they are in CLOSE_WAIT state for a long time(almost forever).  And when many links are accessed it could result in FD limits being reached. The potential issue is that when using rvest, gc() call does not release it from CLOSE_WAIT. And there is no way to release it. At least I have observed these hold ups for >3 hours.

Comment: So i dont think curl itself is the issue. The above examples were to show that in such cases rvest is probably keeping the handle alive.

Comment: Yes that is a feature. See ?handle_pool in the httr package. You must be doing pretty crazy things to run out of file descriptors.

Comment: I agree! I dont think FD limit is the issue. Probably there is some other stuff its hitting. Just trying to see why stuff is hanging. Thanks for all the pointers, very helpful!